# List append is returning two different lists

Tags: python, list, while-loop, append

```
import requests
import json

def decrementList(words):
    for w in [words] + [words[:-x] for x in range(1,len(words))]:
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='
        request = requests.get(url + "%20".join(w))

        json_dict = json.loads(request.content)
        track_title = ' '.join(w)

        for track in json_dict["tracks"]:
            if track["name"].lower() == track_title.lower() and track['href']:
                return "http://open.spotify.com/track/" + track["href"][14:], words[len(w):], track["href"][14:]

    return "Sorry, no more track matches found!", None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    message = "baby asdf".split()
    size = len(message)

    while message:
        href, new_list, for_playlist = decrementList(message)
        message = new_list

        #print href

        playlist = []
        playlist.append(for_playlist)
        print playlist
```

In the code above, `print playlist`is returning two separate lists.  I realize that this is occurring because the list append happens within a while loop.  How can I make these both append to the same empty list, not two separate lists?

Comment: try `.extend()` instead of `.append()` - but you probably don't want to set `playlist` to an empty list each time through the loop either

Comment: i had tried that, and i tried again and it returns this `[u'4', u'k', u'd', u'Y', u'l', u'V', u'x', u'g', u'8', u'P', u'd', u'i', u'V', u'L', u'z', u'X', u'D', u'G', u'Y', u'g', u'e', u'T']
[u'4', u'Q', u'E', u'k', u'W', u'r', u'P', u'h', u's', u'y', u'l', u'z', u'l', u'L', u't', u'T', u'5', u'd', u'r', u'4', u'K', u't']`

Comment: how can i not make playlist empty each time through?

Comment: LOL - don't *force* it to be empty each time through ;-)

Comment: i am being very silly today. the correct answers below make me feel so stupid!

Comment: It happens to everyone :-)  Just never let it happen again ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make *declaration* of list and *print* out of `while loop`:

```
playlist = []
while message:
    #....
print playlist
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you reassign the name `playlist` to an empty list before calling `append()`:

```
playlist = []
```

If you put it before the `while` loop, you should get the expected result.

```
playlist = []
while message:
```